# Possible to code webapi site but deliver as TFS extension (with on-premises TFS)?

Tags: tfs

Wondering if there is a way to develop a standard web site (webapi coded with c# or F# using the REST API to communicate with on-premises TFS), but deliver pages to the TFS web page as an extension.  From the documentation I am seeing, it looks like you may be required to code strictly in javascript.  But I would prefer to code my logic and page construction with C#/F#.

I would be hosting the web site on my TFS server machine under IIS.

Answer (score 0):

Your extension can only contain Javascript. You can have the extension call out of iframe data from your app though. From a deployment standpoint, you'd have to ship the extension and the C# app separately. There is no way to package a web app in an extension and have it deployed automatically.

Comment: Thank you for your response.  One more question, if I might.  I am not planning to share this extension.  So if I understand your answer correctly, I would have a separate C# app running that I would call to from my extension web site (which itself would be entirely javascript, coded and packaged according to the numerous examples available)?  When you say "call out of iframe data from your app" do you mean that client javascript running from my extension would make rest calls to my other app?  Still a bit shaky on my conception of this, so I would appreciate some additional clarity.  Thanks.

Comment: The BaseUri of the extension will allow you to load the content of your extension from your own IIS application. You can then use the VSTS API to render UI, the VSTS REST API to call the VSTS backend and your own WebAPI functions.

Comment: Thanks again very much!

Comment: One more question about this, if I may.  I have created a standard Visual-Studio-generated mvc project and am trying to figure out how to send the results of a controller request to my tfs hub extension.  Now as I understand it, the extension is expecting to receive a static html file from the site I configured with the baseUri parameter in the manifest.  I configured the contributions/properties/uri parameter as Home/Index.html, which I'm thinking would be combined with the baseUri to be the request URL. (continued in next comment)

Comment: I also added route handling to my mvc app to take a request for an html file and route it to a controller action with the same name (so a request for Home/Index.html routes to the Home controller's Index method.  But the request is hanging when the hub page loads and I suspect it might be because the response is not what the extension is expecting.  If I figure out how to send back an actual Index.Html file, will this likely do the trick?  Or is there some piece I'm missing in how one configures the manifest for baseUri usage?

Comment: Sorry for the noise.  Never mind.  It actually works.  I had somehow dragged one of my cshtml pages to another folder and this was the problem.  So what I described above works perfectly.

Comment: @MClagett If the issue was resolved by the answer, then you could Accept it as an Answer, This can be beneficial to other community members reading this thread.

Answer (score 0):

Got this working.  The end result is that a standard  ssl) and to define a hub in the vas-extension.json file.  The hub adds a new page onto whatever hub group you configure it to be under (I specified the Work hub group).  This added a new link alongside the Backlog and Board links that were already present.  The only tricky thing I did (and I'm not sure this is needed) was to define a new route in the mvc route configuration that maps a request for an incoming .html page to whatever controller and method match the page request with the .html extension removed.  This allowed me to configure the target uri as an html page (in my case Home /Index.html), as I wasn't sure whether or not the TFS extensions need to work only with static resources like .html pages.  This allowed me to code all my server back-end in C#.  In the vsts-extension.json file I did not specify any static files to be uploaded with the extension.

Comment: Some of the message above got deleted.  The second sentence should read "The end result is that a standard asp.net mvc web site can be hosted inside a TFS extension page.  The key was to use the baseUri tag (the site must support SSL) ...